How to wrap word with previous word if only last word does not fit
I have a text of different sizes it might fit 1-3 lines usually. I am building the text with annotated string and the last two words is always "search everywhere". However, I got a problem I where I need the word "search" to wrap with "everywhere".
For example:
Wrong case:
This is long text and it has wrap SEARCH |(end of line)
Everhwere
Right case:
This is long text and it has wrap (space here) |(end of line)
SEARCH Everhwere
I tried separating with two different Text() composable but I was not able to start second Text() right after the multilined Text()

You should use a non-breaking space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you want to make sure that there never is a line break between the two words, you can use the constant nbsp which is the Kotlin non-breakable whitespace character.
import kotlin.text.Typography.nbsp
//...

append("SEARCH")
append(nbsp)
append("everywhere")

If you "SEARCH everywhere" to simply appear on a new line, use the \n string:
append("\nSEARCH everywhere")

